# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 AFNetworking with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, cocoapods, afnetworking

Can anybody help me with this, its driving me crazy. I looked at every post I could find with a similar issue, and none of it worked.

I installed AFNetworking 3.0 in my project with Cocoapods, it installed, I see the AFNetworking pod in my project.Set built Architure only :YES Whenever I try to build I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
          "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
              objc-class-ref in EFServer.o
          "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestSerializer", referenced from:
              objc-class-ref in EFServer.o
          "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
              objc-class-ref in EFServer.o
          "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MBProgressHUD", referenced from:
              objc-class-ref in EFServer.o
        ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
        clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem after installing pods to my old project. In my case there where custom linker flags added to the Build Settings of the target, but the $(inherited) was removed so the pods flags were missing (not inherited) therefore no AFNetworking framework were linked.

I suggest to check out is there a **$(inherited)** row added to the **Other Linker Flags** section of **Build Settings** for the target.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete the `DerivedData` folder and re-try.

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Answer (score 1):

**add below lines to your podfile and reinstall it and add your project name to target.**

```
target 'your project name' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end
```

hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: My pod file   source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'EasyFood' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '3.1.0'
end

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'EasyFood' do
    pod 'AFNetworking', '3.1.0'
end

pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'

Comment: add 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2' this line after AFNetworking.

Comment: Any Other Solution to Solve this error. This All solution are not working.